# Line Spacing for NSAttributedString with Multiple Fonts and FontSizes

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I have a string that I want to set in a UILabel or UITextView and have no line spacing or very little.  I know that NSParagraph style has max and min lineHeight as well as lineHeightMultiple.  I have tried all and still get weird results. It might be that baseline offset attribute needs to also be used but if so how do you find the dynamic value to keep the line spacing even and very little between lines?
[image: CurrentExample]

Here is an example.  To save anyone work I have a switch so that each string could use it's own paragraph style.

```
//: A UIKit based Playground for presenting user interface

import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        let label = UILabel()
        label.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 200, width: 200, height: 20)
        label.text = "Hello World!"
        label.textColor = .black
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        view.addSubview(label)
        self.view = view


        let tryWithIndParagraphStyles = false
        if tryWithIndParagraphStyles{
            let mutAttr = NSMutableAttributedString()
            let para = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            para.alignment = .center

            //WE COULD TRY LINE HEIGHT OR LINE HEIGHT MULTIPLE but the spacing is still wrong
            //        para.lineHeightMultiple = 0.75



            //we could manually set the line heights for each
            let firstFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 75.56262594898386)
            let firstPara = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            firstPara.alignment = .center
            firstPara.minimumLineHeight = firstFont.pointSize - firstFont.ascender + firstFont.capHeight
            firstPara.maximumLineHeight = firstFont.pointSize - firstFont.ascender + firstFont.capHeight
            let firstStr = NSAttributedString(string: "HEY\r", attributes: [.font:firstFont,.paragraphStyle:firstPara])
            mutAttr.append(firstStr)

            let secondFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 24.099621199347652)
            let secondPara = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            secondPara.alignment = .center

            secondPara.minimumLineHeight = secondFont.pointSize - secondFont.ascender + secondFont.capHeight
            secondPara.maximumLineHeight = secondFont.pointSize - secondFont.ascender + secondFont.capHeight
            let secondStr = NSAttributedString(string: "BEGGING TO\r", attributes: [.font:secondFont,.paragraphStyle:secondPara])
            mutAttr.append(secondStr)


            let thirdFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 59.53419014162365)
            let thirdPara = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            thirdPara.alignment = .center

            thirdPara.minimumLineHeight = thirdFont.pointSize - thirdFont.ascender + thirdFont.capHeight
            thirdPara.maximumLineHeight = thirdFont.pointSize - thirdFont.ascender + thirdFont.capHeight
            let thirdStr = NSAttributedString(string: "TEST\r", attributes: [.font:thirdFont,.paragraphStyle:thirdPara])
            mutAttr.append(thirdStr)

            let fourthFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20.96469640066495)

            let fourthPara = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            fourthPara.alignment = .center

            fourthPara.minimumLineHeight = fourthFont.pointSize - fourthFont.ascender + fourthFont.capHeight
            thirdPara.maximumLineHeight = fourthFont.pointSize - fourthFont.ascender + fourthFont.capHeight
            let fourthStr = NSAttributedString(string: "HAMBURGERS", attributes: [.font:fourthFont,.paragraphStyle:fourthPara])
            mutAttr.append(fourthStr)

            label.attributedText = mutAttr
            label.sizeToFit()
        }else{
            let mutAttr = NSMutableAttributedString()
            let para = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            para.alignment = .center

            //WE COULD TRY LINE HEIGHT OR LINE HEIGHT MULTIPLE but the spacing is still wrong
            para.lineHeightMultiple = 0.75



            //we could manually set the line heights for each
            let firstFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 75.56262594898386)
            let firstStr = NSAttributedString(string: "HEY\r", attributes: [.font:firstFont,.paragraphStyle:para])
            mutAttr.append(firstStr)

            let secondStr = NSAttributedString(string: "BEGGING TO\r", attributes: [.font:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 24.099621199347652),.paragraphStyle:para])
            mutAttr.append(secondStr)

            let thirdStr = NSAttributedString(string: "TEST\r", attributes: [.font:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 59.53419014162365),.paragraphStyle:para])
            mutAttr.append(thirdStr)

            let fourthStr = NSAttributedString(string: "HAMBURGERS", attributes: [.font:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20.96469640066495),.paragraphStyle:para])
            mutAttr.append(fourthStr)

            label.attributedText = mutAttr
            label.sizeToFit()
        }
    }
}
// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

Comment: You're playing with the wrong attribute. Consider the `paragraphSpacingBefore`.

Comment: @matt I have played with that one as well.  How would I find the dynamic value to adjust that value.  and would it entail knowing the previous lines font or the current lines font

Comment: I am pretty sure paragraphSpacingBefore won't get it done since it cannot be negative to bring the lines closer together

Comment: Maybe combined with simple `paragraphSpacing`?

Comment: I don’t think it can be negative. I think baseline offset can be but maybe the carriage messes this up. I have been digging on this for a long time. I have not found any reasonable examples of this which is surprising.